# Amazon Redshift not allowing UPDATE + JOIN on existing tables and not find appropriate columns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, amazon-redshift

Using Amazon Redshift to update some columns

I have two tables:

```
Table A                                   

   A        B        C         D
0  23as     asd      adf      [NULL]
1  23as     asd      adf      [NUll]
2  23as     asd      adf      [NUll]

Table B                                   

   A        B        C         D
0  23as     asd      adf      4234
1  23as     asd      adf      5454
2  23as     asd      adf      7867
```

I am trying to populate tableA.D with tableB.D in a join but the error I am getting is that

```
"SQL Error [500310] [42703]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "d" of relation "tableA" does not exist;
  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "d" of relation "tableA" does not exist;
    com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "d" of relation "tableA" does not exist;
```

Here is my update/join statement:

```
update tableA
set d= tableB.d
from tableB
where 
    tableA.A= tableB.A and
    tableB.C= 'Completed '
```

What am I doing wrong that this simple UPDATE + JOIN is not working, and it is not finding the column in the table?

Comment: The query seems find to me. Are you use you have a column `d` in `tableA`? Try `SELECT d FROM tableA LIMIT 1`. Does it return an error?

Comment: just ran your SELECT statement and no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a moron I was spelling the table name incorrectly.